# How can I get the name of my Windows Service at runtime?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a new Windows Service I'm making in C# 4.0.

I'm trying to drop in some event logging code I wrote a while ago which is in a seperate class.

I want to set the event source to the name of the Windows Service without having to change the code next time I drop it into a service.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
String source = Application.Name
```

But I can't seem to find what I'm after anywhere.

Any takers?

Comment: One problem you have is that a single process can host more than one service. In that case, how do you figure out which one you need to find the name of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the code is within the service application, you could do

```
String source = this.ServiceName;
```

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to call a static property.
Unless you write your own static wrapper to get the value of the ServiceName property of your ServiceBase derived class.